# How to add delay after each audio ConcatenatingAudioSource?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

How to add delay after the audio played with concatenating source audio with a delay of 2 seconds is there any methods in the package please guide on this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 listenAudio() {
audioPlayer.sequenceStateStream.listen((event) {
  if (autodelay) {
    audioPlayer.pause();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      audioPlayer.play();
    });
  }}
```

call this method in initstate this works very well .